# Where is app_id value stored in xcode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I've lost 2 hours searching the apple developer docs, google, and stackoverflow. Where can I find my project's app_id in Xcode 6?

I am trying to adapt the apple keychain sample code `https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007797-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_11`

but I've never had to use my app_id before. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: APP ID, you can find in iTunes Connect!

Comment: @JNYJ I am looking here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html but this doesn't tell me how to access the value of App ID in my xcode project. All it says is Apple ID: "A unique number that Apple assigns to the app." Where do I get this value assigned to my project (a project not published in app store)?

Comment: When you app created in iTunes Connect, apple assigns a app_id to your APP, then you can check it in "More->About This App". but i don't know this app_id that you can get in XCODE!, i have not idea!

Comment: When you published it, this APP(app_id) will be available, otherwise not! 
if you want to using this app_id, just copy it from iTunes Contents page.

Comment: Then how can I install and use Keychain capabilities in my app before it is time to publish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notes: When you app created in iTunes Connect, apple assigns a app_id to your APP, then you can check it in "More->About This App"

**Method: getSecureValueForKey**

**Method: storeSecureValue**

```
#import "JNYJKeyChain.h"

@implementation JNYJKeyChain


+ (NSString *)getSecureValueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
/*
     Return a value from the keychain
 */

// Retrieve a value from the keychain
NSDictionary *result = nil;
NSArray *keys = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kSecClass, kSecAttrAccount, kSecReturnAttributes, nil] autorelease];
NSArray *objects = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kSecClassGenericPassword, key, kCFBooleanTrue, nil] autorelease];
NSDictionary *query = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: objects forKeys: keys];

// Check if the value was found
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef) query, (CFTypeRef *) &result);
[query release];
if (status != noErr) {
    // Value not found
    return nil;
} else {
    // Value was found so return it
    NSString *value = [NSString stringWithString:(NSString *) [result objectForKey: (NSString *) kSecAttrGeneric]];
    [result release];
    return value;
}
}

+ (BOOL)storeSecureValue:(NSString *)value forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    /*
 Store a value in the keychain
 */

// Get the existing value for the key
NSString *existingValue = [self getSecureValueForKey:key];

// Check if a value already exists for this key
OSStatus status;
if (existingValue) {
    // Value already exists, so update it
    NSArray *keys = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kSecClass, kSecAttrAccount, nil] autorelease];
    NSArray *objects = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kSecClassGenericPassword, key, nil] autorelease];
    NSDictionary *query = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: objects forKeys: keys] autorelease];
    status = SecItemUpdate((CFDictionaryRef) query, (CFDictionaryRef) [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:value forKey: (NSString *) kSecAttrGeneric]);
} else {
    // Value does not exist, so add it
    NSArray *keys = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kSecClass, kSecAttrAccount, kSecAttrGeneric, nil] autorelease];
    NSArray *objects = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kSecClassGenericPassword, key, value, nil] autorelease];
    NSDictionary *query = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: objects forKeys: keys] autorelease];
    status = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef) query, NULL);
}

// Check if the value was stored
if (status != noErr) {
    // Value was not stored
    return false;
} else {
    // Value was stored
    return true;
}
}

@end
```